# Como colocar .vbs dentro do .bat

Tags: batch, vbs

Estou montando um projeto e não consegui colocar o arquivo `.vbs` dentro do `.bat`.

**cadastro.bat**:

```
    @echo off
    :Menu
    cls
    echo.ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                  ESCOLHA UMA DAS OP€åES ABAIXO E TECLE ENTER                º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.ÌÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¹
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º  [1] ADICIONAR                                                              º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º  [2] BUSCAR                                                                 º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.º                                                                             º
    echo.ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
    echo.          PC NAME ( %USERNAME% ) DATA: %date%  HORA: %time:~0,5%            
    echo. ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
    set /p opt1= Digite a op‡ao:
    if "%opt1%"=="" goto Error
    if %opt1%==1 goto:Adicionar else goto:Error
    if %opt1%==2 goto:BusCodigo else goto:Error
    :Error
    cls
    echo.
    echo.ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
    echo.º                               º
    echo.º    Houve um erro.             º
    echo.º Foi digitado valor incorreto  º
    echo.º Digite o numero correto.      º
    echo.ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
    rem pause>nul
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo.
    echo  VOLTANDO A TELA ANTERIOR...
    goto:Menu

    :Adicionar
    cls
    color 0b
    title SYSTEM - Adicionar Registro
    echo.ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
    echo.º                                                      º                      º
    echo.º                    ADICIONAR REGISTRO                º [V] VOLTAR AO MENU   º
    echo.º                                                      º                      º
    echo.ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
    rem ###Nesta linha Caso nao exista o arquivo para gravacao e leitura sera criado o arquivo com codigo zero "0" .###
    if NOT exist Cont echo 0 > Cont
    if NOT exist Cont2 echo 0 > Cont2

    set /p cod=< Cont
    set /a cod=%cod%+1

    set /p codg=< Cont2
    set /a codg=%codg%+1
    echo  %date%  %time:~0,5%
    echo  Codigo: %cod%
    echo.ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
    rem ###Obtendo dadas para a gravacao###.
    set codigo=%cod%
    set codig=%codg%
    echo.

    :Cad1
    set /p Nome= NOME :

    FOR /F "DELIMS=0123456789" %%§ IN ("%Nome%") DO (
    GOTO :Cad2
    )
    IF "%Nome%"=="" goto Campo1Branco
    if %Nome%==v CLS&goto Redireciona
    if %Nome%==V CLS&goto Redireciona
    GOTO :ERRO

    :Campo1Branco

    echo CAMPO EM BRANCO, DIGITE UM VALOR!

    goto Cad1

    :ERRO
    echo VOCE DIGITOU (%Nome%) DIGITE SOMENTE LETRAS
    echo.
    GOTO :Cad1

    :Cad2
    echo.
    set /p telf= TELEFONE :

    if %telf%==v CLS&goto Redireciona
    if %telf%==V CLS&goto Redireciona

    FOR /F "DELIMS=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ" %%§ IN ("%telf%") DO (
    GOTO :Gravar
      )
    IF "%telf%"=="" goto Campo2Branco
    GOTO :ERRO2

    :Campo2Branco

    echo CAMPO EM BRANCO, DIGITE UM VALOR!

    goto Cad2

    :ERRO2
    rem CLS
    echo VOCE DIGITOU (%telf%) DIGITE SOMENTE NUMEROS
    echo.
    GOTO :Cad2

    rem ###Fim da obtencao dos dadas.###

    echo ------------------

    rem ###Gravando os dados###
    :Gravar
    echo. %codigo% > Cont
    echo. %codig% > Cont2
    echo %codigo%__Nome:............[ %Nome% ] >>Registros
    echo %codigo%__Telefone:........[ %telf% ] >>Registros
    echo %codigo%__Data:............[ %date% ] >>Registros
    echo %codigo%__Hora:............[ %time:~0,5% ] >>Registros
    echo.                                      >> Registros
    echo PC NAME( %USERNAME% ) Login:(%login%) Adicionou o Registro nº (%codigo%) data e hora:(%date% %time:~0,5%) >> Log_Adicionar_Registros.txt
    rem ###Fim da gravacao dos dados###


    echo REGISTRO ADICIONADO COM EXITO...
    ping localhost -n 2.8 >nul
    echo VOLTANDO AO MENU PRINCIPAL...
    ping localhost -n 2.8 >nul
    cls
    Goto Menu

    :BusCodigo
    cls
    echo.ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
    echo.º                                                      º                      º
    echo.º                      BUSCAR CODIGO                   º     [V] VOLTAR       º
    echo.º                                                      º                      º
    echo.ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
    set /P "codigoPesq=- DIGITE O CODIGO PARA PESQUISAR: "
    if %codigoPesq%==v CLS&goto Menu
    if %codigoPesq%==V CLS&goto Menu
    cls
    echo.ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
    echo.º                                                      º                      º
    echo.º                      RESULTADOS BUSCAR CODIGO        º     [V] VOLTAR       º
    echo.º                                                      º                      º
    echo.ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
    echo.
    if exist Registros find  /I "%codigoPesq%__" Registros
    echo.
    echo.
    set /p opcao3= DESEJA EXPORTAR ? (S-SIM / N-NAO):
    if %opcao3%== s goto:Export else goto :Error
    if %opcao3%== S goto:Export else goto :Error
    if %opcao3%== n goto:Buscar else goto :Error
    if %opcao3%== N goto:Buscar else goto :Error
    echo.

    :Export

      For /f "delims=" %%i in ('Cscript //nologo "script_.vbs" "Selecione uma pasta"') do Set "folder=%%i\%codigoPesq%__RELATORIO.txt"
 For /f "eol=- delims=" %%i in ('find /I "%codigoPesq%__" Registros') do >>"%folder%" Echo.%%i



    START %folder%
    ECHO.
    ECHO.
    ECHO.
    ECHO.
    ECHO                      VERIFIQUE O LOCAL [%folder%]
    ECHO.
    echo.
    echo                      ENTER PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL
    pause>nul

    Goto :Menu
```

**Este é o script_.vbs**

```
Dim objFolder, objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Selecione uma pasta.", &H4000, 0)
If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
   wscript.echo objFolder.Self.path
Else
   wscript.echo 0
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode gerar o `.vbs` em tempo de execução do seu batch:

```
echo Dim objFolder^, objShell > script_.vbs
echo Set objShell ^= CreateObject^(^"Shell.Application^"^) >> script_.vbs
echo Set objFolder ^= objShell.BrowseForFolder^(0^, ^"Selecione uma pasta.^"^, ^&H4000, 0^) >> script_.vbs
echo If Not ^(objFolder Is Nothing^) Then >> script_.vbs
echo    wscript.echo objFolder.Self.path >> script_.vbs
echo Else >> script_.vbs
echo    wscript.echo 0 >> script_.vbs
echo End If >> script_.vbs
```

Repare que coloquei algums `^`, pois existem alguns caracteres especiais, e precisamos escapar deles:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO AMIGO.

Answer (score 2):

> - ***Update (agora que me caiu a ficha!) `Bat` + `VBS` num só arquivo `Bat`!??***

---

- O que você busca é ter um ****`Bat/VBS`**** num só arquivo, ou seja, um script hibrido de ****`Bat & VBS`****?

---

É possível usando **[tag](/questions/tagged/tag) de comentários na parte/execução do bat e vbs**, fazendo o script bat tartar comentarios na execução bat, e chamar a si mesmo para ser executado no **`CScritpt.exe`** , onde, na parte VBS, o código em **`bat`** fica entre tags de comentários, na execução do VBS:

---

### o escopo fica assim:

```bat
<!-- :: *// comentário, ignorada no bat e usada como comentário na execução VBS
seus comandos/linhas do bat vão entrar aqui!... 
seus comandos/linhas do bat vão entrar aqui!... 
....
em alguma momento, seu comando é para chamar/rodar em VBS...
....
continua os seus comandos/linhas do bat continuam aqui!... 
continua os seus comandos/linhas do bat continuam aqui!...
..... 
exit /b  *// finaliza execução do bat e ...
# -->    *// fecha comentário bat/vbs
<job><script language="vbscript"> *// inicio do código em VBS
 seus códigos/linhas em vbs vai entrar aqui
 seus códigos/linhas em vbs vai entrar aqui
...
</script></job>*// fim do código em VBS
```

---

> - Exemplo já portando para o seu **`Bat c/ VBS`** dentro/junto num só, ficaria assim:

```bat
<!-- :: 
@echo off
:Menu
cls
echo.Ã‰ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ»
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                  ESCOLHA UMA DAS OPâ‚¬Ã¥ES ABAIXO E TECLE ENTER                Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.ÃŒÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ¹
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº  [1] ADICIONAR                                                              Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº  [2] BUSCAR                                                                 Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.Âº                                                                             Âº
echo.ÃˆÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ¼
echo.          PC NAME ( %USERNAME% ) DATA: %date%  HORA: %time:~0,5%            
echo. ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃ
set /p opt1= Digite a opâ€¡ao:
if "%opt1%"=="" goto Error
if %opt1%==1 goto:Adicionar else goto:Error
if %opt1%==2 goto:BusCodigo else goto:Error
:Error
cls
echo.
echo.Ã‰ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ»
echo.Âº                               Âº
echo.Âº    Houve um erro.             Âº
echo.Âº Foi digitado valor incorreto  Âº
echo.Âº    Houve um erro.             Âº
echo.Âº Foi digitado valor incorreto  Âº
echo.Âº Digite o numero correto.      Âº
echo.ÃˆÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ¼
rem pause>nul
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo  VOLTANDO A TELA ANTERIOR...
goto:Menu

:Adicionar
cls
color 0b
title SYSTEM - Adicionar Registro
echo.Ã‰ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ»
echo.Âº                                                      Âº                      Âº
echo.Âº                    ADICIONAR REGISTRO                Âº [V] VOLTAR AO MENU   Âº
echo.Âº                                                      Âº                      Âº
echo.ÃˆÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ¼
rem ###Nesta linha Caso nao exista o arquivo para gravacao e leitura sera criado o arquivo com codigo zero "0" .###
if NOT exist Cont echo 0 > Cont
if NOT exist Cont2 echo 0 > Cont2

set /p cod=< Cont
set /a cod=%cod%+1

set /p codg=< Cont2
set /a codg=%codg%+1
echo  %date%  %time:~0,5%
echo  Codigo: %cod%
echo.ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃ
rem :: ###Obtendo dadas para a gravacao###.
set codigo=%cod%
set codig=%codg%
echo.

:Cad1
set /p Nome= NOME :

FOR /F "DELIMS=0123456789" %%Â§ IN ("%Nome%")DO GOTO:Cad2
)
IF "%Nome%"=="" goto Campo1Branco
if %Nome%==v CLS&goto Redireciona
if %Nome%==V CLS&goto Redireciona
GOTO :ERRO

:Campo1Branco

echo CAMPO EM BRANCO, DIGITE UM VALOR!

goto Cad1

:ERRO
echo VOCE DIGITOU (%Nome%) DIGITE SOMENTE LETRAS
echo.
GOTO :Cad1

:Cad2
echo.
set /p telf= TELEFONE :

if %telf%==v CLS&goto Redireciona
if %telf%==V CLS&goto Redireciona

FOR /F "DELIMS=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ" %%Â§ IN ("%telf%")DO GOTO:Gravar

IF "%telf%"=="" goto Campo2Branco
GOTO :ERRO2

:Campo2Branco

echo CAMPO EM BRANCO, DIGITE UM VALOR!

goto Cad2

:ERRO2
rem CLS
echo VOCE DIGITOU (%telf%) DIGITE SOMENTE NUMEROS
echo.
GOTO :Cad2

rem ###Fim da obtencao dos dadas.###

echo ------------------

rem ###Gravando os dados###
:Gravar
echo. %codigo% > Cont
echo. %codig% > Cont2
echo %codigo%__Nome:............[ %Nome% ] >>Registros
echo %codigo%__Telefone:........[ %telf% ] >>Registros
echo %codigo%__Data:............[ %date% ] >>Registros
echo %codigo%__Hora:............[ %time:~0,5% ] >>Registros
echo.                                      >> Registros & (
echo PC NAME( %USERNAME% ) Login:(%login%) Adicionou o Registro nÂº (%codigo%) data e hora:(%date% %time:~0,5%)
) >> Log_Adicionar_Registros.txt
rem ###Fim da gravacao dos dados###

echo REGISTRO ADICIONADO COM EXITO...
ping localhost -n 2.8 >nul
echo VOLTANDO AO MENU PRINCIPAL...
ping localhost -n 2.8 >nul
cls
Goto Menu

:BusCodigo
cls
echo.Ã‰ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ»
echo.Âº                                                      Âº                      Âº
echo.Âº                      BUSCAR CODIGO                   Âº     [V] VOLTAR       Âº
echo.Âº                                                      Âº                      Âº
echo.ÃˆÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ¼
set /P "codigoPesq=- DIGITE O CODIGO PARA PESQUISAR: "
if %codigoPesq%==v CLS&goto Menu
if %codigoPesq%==V CLS&goto Menu
cls
echo.Ã‰ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ»
echo.Âº                                                      Âº                      Âº
echo.Âº                      RESULTADOS BUSCAR CODIGO        Âº     [V] VOLTAR       Âº
echo.Âº                                                      Âº                      Âº
echo.ÃˆÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÃÂ¼
echo.
if exist Registros find  /I "%codigoPesq%__" Registros
echo.
echo.
set /p opcao3= DESEJA EXPORTAR ? (S-SIM / N-NAO):
if %opcao3%== s goto:Export else goto :Error
if %opcao3%== S goto:Export else goto :Error
if %opcao3%== n goto:Buscar else goto :Error
if %opcao3%== N goto:Buscar else goto :Error
echo.

:Export
 rem                      Cscript //nologo "script_.vbs" "Selecione uma pasta"
For /f "tokens=*delims= " %%i in ('CScript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf"')do Set "folder=%%i\%codigoPesq%__RELATORIO.txt"
For /f "eol=-delims=" %%i in ('find /I "%codigoPesq%__" Registros')do >>"%folder%" Echo.%%i

START %folder%
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO                      VERIFIQUE O LOCAL [%folder%]
ECHO.
echo.
echo                      ENTER PARA VOLTAR AO MENU PRINCIPAL
pause>nul

Goto :Menu
Rem :: soh pa previnir erro de fluxo entre operações dos lables :: 
exit /b 

# --><job><script language="vbscript">
Option Explicit
Dim strPath
strPath = SelectFolder( "" )
If strPath = vbNull Then
    WScript.Echo "Cancelled"
Else
    WScript.Echo strPath
End If
Function SelectFolder( myStartFolder )
    Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell
    On Error Resume Next
    SelectFolder = vbNull
    Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Selecione uma pasta.", &H4000, myStartFolder )
    If IsObject( objfolder ) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path
    Set objFolder = Nothing 
    Set objshell  = Nothing
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
</script></job>
```

---

---

- Ter o bat e o vbs rodando no mesmo arquivo?

> - **Observações** para quando o ******`bat`****** for gerar o **VBS**:

Nos **caracteres  especiais** que serão ecoados e estão **dentro de aspas**, você  não precisa usar escapes, igualmente nas aspas, nas virgulas e no sinal de igual, estes caracteres não irão precisar de escapes, use o echo direto.

> Abaixo um forma mais "compacta".

```bat
@echo off & >"%temp%\script_.vbs"^
    (echo/Dim objFolder, objShell & echo/ Set objShell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
     echo/ Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder^(0, "Selecione uma pasta.", ^&H4000, 0^)
     echo/ If Not ^(objFolder Is Nothing^) Then & echo/ wscript.echo objFolder.Self.path 
     echo/Else & echo/ wscript.echo 0 & echo/End If)
```

> Abaixo uma forma "expandida".

```bat
@echo off & >"%temp%\script_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Dim objFolder, objShell 
     echo/ Set objShell = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)
     echo/ Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder^(0, "Selecione uma pasta.", ^&H4000, 0^)
     echo/ If Not ^(objFolder Is Nothing^) Then
     echo/  wscript.echo objFolder.Self.path 
     echo/ Else 
     echo/  wscript.echo 0 
     echo/ End If
    )
```